# Access existing Bootstrap variables within custom variables file

Tags: css, variables, sass, bootstrap-5

If I am importing the `/boostrap/scss/_variables.scss` file AFTER my custom `./variables.scss` file, why can't I access existing global variables of the origin `_variables.scss` file? Since Bootstrap often uses cascading variable assignments thats a problem since all variables are undefined at first when i include my custom file beforehand.

This is the way i am doing it currently since the Bootstrap docs state that:

```
// Custom Variables
@import 'variables';
// Variables
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables';
```

If i want to be able to access variables of the `/boostrap/scss/_variables.scss` file, would the right way be a duplicate import like that ?

```
// Variables
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables';
// Custom Variables
@import 'variables';
// Variables
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables';
```

Comment: Why is your custom stylesheet loaded first? That's not standard in my experience. Then, why do you need to import the existing variables? Simply overwrite them in your file.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a bootstrap file which contains all other files of bootstrap,so include only this one listed below and then call your variable.scss file.

**@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";**

**@import "variable.scss"** //Custom scss file

For more information you can visit : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/

Comment: But  this is NOT the way bootstrap recommends it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/#importing